# Django HttpResponse returning object instead of stated string

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I am using Django and React. I need to send a string from Django to React. I have tried using both HttpResponse and JsonResponse but both seem to be returning a response object that does not include the data.

The response object from React looks like this:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8000/post/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
   body: (...)
   bodyUsed: false
   headers: Headers {}
   ok: true
   redirected: false
   status: 200
   statusText: "OK"
   type: "cors"
   url: "http://localhost:8000/post/"
   __proto__: Response
```

Here is my Django

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def index(request):
    string1 = ""
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...processing upload...
        string1 = "Hello World"

    return HttpResponse(string1)
```

And my react request looks like this:

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(file)
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/post/", {
       method: "POST",
       body: formData,
       enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

How can I get the data I need (string1) included in the response object (or without the response object)? I've looked on StackOverflow and around the web and haven't found a solution. I am also not sure whether this is a problem with Django or React but it seems like a Django problem. (Also, I don't believe it is a CORS Problem as I have CORS are allowed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does include the data, as payload, but that makes it less *accessible*, especially if you later plan to pass multiple items. You can wrap the result in a JSON blob:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def index(request):
    string1 = ''
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # … processing upload …
        string1 = 'Hello World'

    return JsonResponse({'result': string1})
```

In the JavaScript part, you can then interpret the response as JSON and deserialize it:

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(file)
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/post/", {
       method: "POST",
       body: formData,
       enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    }).then(response => {
      response.json().then(data => {
        console.log(data.result);
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, I had tried using JsonResponse before but my mistake was the second .then(). Can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Django that is adding all those attributes. That's just the standard fetch Response. You can access your text data through the Response object as follows:

```js
fetch('https://stackoverflow.com', {method: 'GET'})
   .then(res => res.text())
   .then(text => console.log(text))
```

In the case of JSON data, you just have to use the .json() method instead of .text():

```js
fetch('https://stackoverflow.com', {method: 'GET'})
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(json => console.log(json))
```

See the documentation for the Response object of the Fetch API: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)